# Identical StreamBuilders in flutter, one is working other returns null

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I have two identical stream builders in two different widgets. One works, while the other is receiving no data. This is the widget tree.

[image]

Here is the `StreamBuilder`

```
StreamBuilder<AudioPlayerState>(
    stream: _playbackProvider.playbackState,
    builder: (context, snapshot) {
      IconData _playbackButton = Icons.play_circle_filled;

         if (snapshot.hasData) {
             if (snapshot.data == AudioPlayerState.PLAYING) {
                  _playbackButton = Icons.pause_circle_filled;
             } else {
                  _playbackButton = Icons.play_circle_filled;
             }
         }

        return OutlineButton(
             onPressed: () {
               _playButtonClicked(snapshot.data);
             },
             child: Icon(_playbackButton),
             shape: CircleBorder(),
        );
}),
```

Here is the stream they are both listening to:

```
Stream<AudioPlayerState> get playbackState {
    return _audioPlayer.onPlayerStateChanged; // using onPlayerStateChanged stream provided by audioplayers plugin.
}
```

This stream can be accessed by the change notifier provider, in both of these widgets (Scaffolds). The audioplayer is enclosed in a ChangeNotifier class.

```
class PlaybackProvider with ChangeNotifier {
  String _path;
  AudioPlayer _audioPlayer;

  PlaybackProvider() {
    _audioPlayer = AudioPlayer();
    _audioPlayer.setReleaseMode(ReleaseMode.STOP);
    _audioPlayer.notificationState = AudioPlayerState.STOPPED;
  }

  Stream<Duration> get playbackPosition { // this stream is also working fine in the first screen (widget)
    return _audioPlayer.onAudioPositionChanged;
  }

  Stream<AudioPlayerState> get playbackState {
    return _audioPlayer.onPlayerStateChanged;
  }

//other methods
}
```

The change notifier is then provided to each of these widgets.

```
final _playbackProvider = Provider.of<PlaybackProvider>(context);
```

And the main function,

```
void main() {
  runApp(MultiProvider(providers: [
    ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) => PlaylistProvider()),
    ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) => PlaybackProvider()),
  ], child: MyApp()));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Stream<Duration> get playbackPosition { // this stream is also working fine in the first screen (widget)
    return _audioPlayer.onAudioPositionChanged;
  }
```

Are you sure _audioPlayer.onAudioPositionChanged is a BroadcastStream or that it returns the same instance of Strem, It could be the case that the getter is returning different instances each time you call it, one way to be sure you have the same value is to create a StreamProvider and then consume it down in the tree

```
void main() {
  runApp(MultiProvider(providers: [
    ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) => PlaylistProvider()),
    ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) => PlaybackProvider()),
    StreamProvider<AudioPlayerState>(create: (context) => Provider.of<PlaybackProvider>(context, listen: false).playbackState)
  ], child: MyApp()));
}
```

And then instead of StreamBuilder in each widget just use the consumer

```
return OutlineButton(
  onPressed: () => _playButtonClicked(snapshot.data),
  child: Consumer<AudioPlayerState>(
    builder: (context, data, _) {
      if(data  == AudioPlayerState.PLAYING) return Icon(Icons.pause_circle_filled);
      return Icon(Icons.play_circle_filled);
    }
  ),
  shape: CircleBorder(),
);
```

Your code and logic is not wrong, but if you're using provider maybe it's better to use all the kind of Providers it provides (unironically) to your advantage. If you want to keep with the StreamBuilder, that's fine too, but without seeing your code of `AudioPlayer` class it's hard to se what is returning `_audioPlayer.onAudioPositionChanged`, if it's a simple stream, are you creating it anew in that method, its Broadcast (using the asBroadCast method), etc?

Comment: Thanks. I was thinking of using StreamProvider too. Ironically, I simple moved the declaration of _playbackProvider outside the build method and simply initialised it with Provider in the build method. It works now. But I like this idea of using consumer with streamprovider. Thanks for pointing me in that direction.

Comment: Now that I think of it, declaring _playbackProvider = Provider.of<PlaybackProvider>(context) without listen: false could lead to rebuild StreamBuilder unnecesary too, but glad you found a way to initiliaze it without problem

Comment: I did but I have no idea how it was not working before but is working now.

Comment: I would like to point here that builder in Consumer required a third Widget argument

Comment: yeah you're right (context, data, child) to pass the widget of the child argument of the Consumer

Comment: This I think, and as you suggested, should be the preferred way instead of using the `StreamBuilder`.